# SQL: The second oldest date

Tags: sql, soql

Imagine you've got a table similar to this:

```
 |email          |   purchase_date      |
 |:--------------|:---------------------|
 |stan@gmail.com |  Jun 30 2020 12:00AM |  
 |stan@gmail.com |  Aug 05 2020 5:00PM  |  
 |stan@gmail.com |  Mar 22 2018 3:00AM  |  
 |eric@yahoo.com |  Aug 05 2020 5:00PM  |  
 |eric@yahoo.com |  Mar 22 2018 3:00PM  |  
 |kyle@gmail.com |  Mar 22 2018 3:00PM  |  
 |kyle@gmail.com |  Jun 30 2020 12:00AM |  
 |kyle@gmail.com |  Aug 05 2020 5:00PM  |  
 |kenny@gmail.com|  Aug 05 2020 5:00PM  |
```

Totally random. The actual database I work with is actually more complex with much more columns.

Both the columns are STRING type. Which is not convenient. The purchase date should be DATE type. Kenny made only one purchase, so there shouldn't be any row for him in the result table.
Also notice that a there's a lot of identical dates.

I'd like to select the email and the 2nd oldest purchase date (named as 'second_purchase') for each email address, so that the result looks like this:

```
|email          | second_purchase      |
|:--------------|:-------------------- |
|stan@gmail.com | Jun 30 2020 12:00AM  | 
|eric@yahoo.com | Aug 05 2021 5:00PM   | 
|kyle@gmail.com | Jun 30 2020 12:00AM  |
```

I can't seem to get the logic or syntax right. I don't want to put all my codes in here, because I've tried many variations of my idea...
It didn't seem to work somehow. But I'd love to see an example code from someone skilled in SQL. My idea is maybe not that great..:-)

This version is actually SOQL (Salesforce Object Query Language). That could be important.

Sorry for not styling the table properly, I didn't seem to work either, even when I used the recommended styling. I wasn't able to post. That was actually quite frustrating.

Anyway, thank you for any help!

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this with SOQL, I can't think of how it would be practical in sql, but SOQL doesn't give you anything to parse the date string to the components you'd need to sort them.  Even if you had the dates stored as dates, I don't think soql would provide anything to partition the results by customer.   I think you'll need to download ALL the data and parse it with some other language.

Comment: Thanks! Hearing that something might not be possible is actually useful, because my mindset is that everything is possible in SQL. You just have to find the right solution... which might in fact not be true. On the other hand, I still think that this particular issue has to have some solution. Moreover, I feel that it is practical. I'd like to calculate differences between the first and second purchase date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following sql which uses a `dense_rank` over each user's email and orders by a casted `purchase_date`

**Query #1**

```
WITH date_converted_table AS (
    SELECT
        email,
        purchase_date,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (
          PARTITION BY email
          ORDER BY CAST(purchase_date as timestamp) ASC
        ) dr
    FROM
        mytable
)
SELECT
    email,
    purchase_date as second_purchase
FROM 
    date_converted_table
WHERE dr=2;
```

| email | second_purchase |
| --- | --- |
| eric@yahoo.com | Aug 05 2020 5:00PM |
| kyle@gmail.com | Jun 30 2020 12:00AM |
| stan@gmail.com | Jun 30 2020 12:00AM |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
    email,
    purchase_date as second_purchase
FROM (
    SELECT
        email,
        purchase_date,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (
          PARTITION BY email
          ORDER BY CAST(purchase_date as timestamp) ASC
        ) dr
    FROM
        mytable
) tb
WHERE dr=2;
```

| email | second_purchase |
| --- | --- |
| eric@yahoo.com | Aug 05 2020 5:00PM |
| kyle@gmail.com | Jun 30 2020 12:00AM |
| stan@gmail.com | Jun 30 2020 12:00AM |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6C44g4NTDLWTqpRqwDjg6h/3)

#### Update 1

As it pertains to follow up question in comment:

> Is it possible to upgrade the result so that there are first_purchase
> dates (where dr=1) adn second_purchase dates (where dr=2) in separate
> columns?

A case expression and aggregation may assist you as shown below. The having clause ensures that there is both a first and second purchase date.

```
SELECT
    email,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN dr=1 THEN purchase_date
    END) as first_purchase,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN dr=2 THEN purchase_date
    END) as second_purchase
FROM (
    SELECT
        email,
        purchase_date,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (
          PARTITION BY email
          ORDER BY CAST(purchase_date as timestamp) ASC
        ) dr
    FROM
        mytable
) tb
GROUP BY email
HAVING
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN dr=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  
    ) > 0 AND
     SUM(
        CASE WHEN dr=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  
    ) > 0;
```

| email | first_purchase | second_purchase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| eric@yahoo.com | Mar 22 2018 3:00PM | Aug 05 2020 5:00PM |
| kyle@gmail.com | Mar 22 2018 3:00PM | Jun 30 2020 12:00AM |
| stan@gmail.com | Mar 22 2018 3:00AM | Jun 30 2020 12:00AM |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6C44g4NTDLWTqpRqwDjg6h/4)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! On DB Fiddle this works as a charm. Very clever. And it's definitely above my SQL level. I will look into it more. But...I am using SOQL language. This solution doesn't work in its environment. The message error I am getting is this: Unable to create temporary data extension: Field name cannot be blank.

Comment: Btw, my layman's opinion is that SOQL is not particularly good accent of SQL family language.

Comment: I am sorry. I've made premature conclusion. The Query #2 actually works even in Salesforce SQL. That's great. I've marked your solution as a correct one. Thank you again!

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade the result so that there are first_purchase dates (where dr=1) adn second_purchase dates (where dr=2) in separate columns?

Comment: @Amberjack You may see an example in the following db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6C44g4NTDLWTqpRqwDjg6h/4

Comment: That's just perfect. You have no idea how immensely you've helped me in understanding of SQL. Thanks a lot!